# Should Kpop be regarded as separate music genre?

Tags: genre, k-pop

Although the K-pop songs have pretty similar beats to the music worldwide, should they be regarded as a separate Genre?

Answer (score 2):

There is no clear unique definition of what music "genre" is, but the music industry, the media and fans refer to K-pop as musical cultural movement with a distinct identity, so that makes it a genre by all accounts (for what it's worth, this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_music_genres_and_styles) quotes K-pop as a distinct genre)

It's not just the purely musical elements that are at stake here, but language, lifestyle, artists images, the whole subculture existing in Korea around K-pop, also contribute to making it a distinct genre.

I recommend to anyone wishing to have a better understanding of K-pop as a cultural phenomenon to check out the interview about the subject that's contained in this podcast ([Sound Opinions June 15, 2012](https://www.soundopinions.org/show/342))

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but I stumbled across it and while Jose's answer touches on this, but I wanted to expand a bit.

K-Pop isn't a single different genre *musically*, it incorporates a lot of genres. If you look at major releases over the last year, you'll find deep house, jersey club, dnb, neo-soul, bubblegum pop, and many others. These are all distinct genres; no one would say that CCR and Cannibal Corpse belong to the same genre just because they're American and use guitars.

What the term K-Pop really applies to is gayo (가요, popular music), along with *all of the post-Seo Taiji industry stuff*. When Lee Soo Man came back from the US and decided to go into the entertainment industry, that set the blueprint for the last few decades of K-Pop: the trainee system, choreo, parasocial relationships, styling, marketing, use by the govt of the ROK for soft power advantages, and fan culture, which collectively are unique to K-Pop (though some elements exist in other scenes).

So while it's really a question of how you define "genre" (just music, or are you including culture in general), K-Pop wouldn't be K-Pop without all of that other stuff, and *can also be K-Pop* without necessarily including Koreans.

Two recent groups that show this are NiziU and XG (to a lesser extent). NiziU at least is *absolutely* K-Pop, even though none of the members are Korean. XG certainly feels like a K-Pop group, and promotes mostly in Korea, even though their company and all of the members are Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I'm of two minds about this. Part of me realizes that, considering it's "Korean Pop", it should be a subclass of the Pop genre, however it's also just another version of what America considers pop. However, with the way that K-Pop is evolving, I would suggest that at this point it has it's own unique style and should be considered it's own genre.